# Returning a cached contact by ID

Tags: c#

This class returns a cached contact by ID. The two cached functions here are doing the same thing. The only difference being an early `return` statement or using `else` and having only one `return` statement. CacheHelper class is a static class that is a wrapper around .Net's MemoryCache class. It's a dll reference so I don't have the source code for it.

I personally think the function with `else` is more readable. However, when I'm reading on the web, it says I need to avoid using `else` whenever possible.

Also, there is a reason I'm checking if cache exists first instead of directly getting it. In some cases, null `Contact` objects are added to the cache, so if I do a get directly, the logic won't be right. Get would return an empty object if the cache didn't exist or even if a null object is stored in the cache. I understand that storing null objects does not make much sense. I'm the in process of refactoring it, so for now please focus only on the question about whether or not to use `else`.

```
public class ContactHelper
{

    public Contact GetContact(int ID)
    {
        return ContactService.GetContact(ID);
    }

    public Contact GetCachedContact(int ID)
    {

        string Key = ID;
        Contact Con = default(Contact);

        if (CacheHelper.Exists(Key)) {
            Con = (Contact)CacheHelper.Get(Key);
        } else {
            Con = GetContact(ID);
            CacheHelper.Add(Key, Con);
        }

        return Con;
    }

    public Contact GetCachedContact_2(int ID)
    {

        String Key = ID

        if (CacheHelper.Exists(Key)){
            return (Contact)CacheHelper.Get(Key);
        }

        Con = GetContact(ID);
        CacheHelper.Add(Key, Con);

        return Con;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's underneath `CacheHelper`? A dictionary?  If so, there are more methods than just `ContainsKey` that can be useful, say for example, `TryGetValue`. Also, do make sure you aren't reinventing the wheel by wrapping a dictionary's methods when the dictionary class itself has all the functionality you need.

Comment: @moarboilerplate CacheHelper is a third party dll. All I know is it uses MemoryCache class of .Net. I don't really know the implementation details of it. It works without any issues though.

Comment: @mdfst13 I added more information about CacheHelper class in my question.

Comment: Does not compile for me.  Cannot implicitly cast int to string.  String Key = ID.  On the second you are missing a ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's debatable on which is more readable. I've worked in places where the common opinion is that an explicit `else` is more readable, and I've worked in places that consider the terser the code, the better.

If I had to choose, I'd personally go for the one without the `else`, because it's less lines of code to maintain, but my general advice is that within the overall picture of developing your app, it probably doesn't matter that much.

If you decide that the way with the `else` is more readable, I wouldn't initialize `Con` at all, because it gets overwritten in either case.